# Как узнать определено ли свойство объекта ViewBag?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Во вьюшке я задаю, или не задаю определённое свойство `ViewBag` - `ViewBag.SomeData`. В файле `_Layout.cshtml` мне надо выводить или не выводить определённый блок в зависимости от того задан ли `SomeData` во `ViewBag`, а как это сделать?

Пока я использую для этого `ViewData` и его функцию `ContainsKey`, но так у меня получается в одних местах `ViewBag` а в других, где надо знать определено ли свойство а где нет - `ViewData`, не очень красиво и то и то использовать. Либо везде надо переходить на `ViewData`.

Answer (score 1):

Просто проверьте это свойство на `null`

```
@if (ViewBag.SomeData != null) {
    // Действия, если SomeData определена
}
else {
    // Действия, если SomeData не определена
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Все данные из `ViewBag` автоматически попадают в словарь `ViewData`, так что вы всегда спокойно можете проверять их через `ViewData.ContainsKey`.

Собственно, `ViewBag` - это динамическая обертка поверх `ViewData`, в этом можно убедиться с помощью кода:

```
PropertyInfo viewDataProperty = ViewBag.GetType()
    .GetProperty("ViewData", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var value = viewDataProperty.GetValue(ViewBag);
Object.ReferenceEquals(value, ViewData); // вернет true
```

C `ViewBag` можно максимум использовать что-то вроде `ViewBag.SomeData != null`, но это не гарантирует отсутствия свойства - оно может присутствовать, но быть равным null.